# Flex String to HTML for parse with DOM

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have a string:

```
private str:String = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>TEST</div>
<span id="t1">T1 Content</span>
<span class="t2">T2 Content</span>
</body>
</html>';
```

I want to parse the string. Next, I get innerHTMl via Object, ID or Class.

E.g.:

```
Objects: Body, Div, Span
IDs: t1
Classes: t2
```

In PHP with [the class](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), it's easy. But I could not create this build with Flex.

Thanks for help...

Comment: I think this question is too broad to be answered on this site.  Maybe you should try to write your own HTML Parser in AS3 and/or try to convert the PHP Class you found then come back to us with specific errors you encountered.

Comment: If it would be XHTML, you could treat it as a regular XML object. But I think the first line of your example is already not compliant.

Comment: I believe as3 will ignore exclatives (<!...>) when creating native XML objects, so the first line should be fine,  if not, you could always extract it with regex or string.replace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to native XML in as3, then use e4x to parse the information required:

```
var xml:XML = XML(str);

//trace the content of any span with the id of "t1"
trace(xms..span.(attribute("id") == "t1"));

//trace the content of any span with the class t2
trace(xml..span.(attribute("class") == "t2"));

//trace the contents of the first div
trace(xml..div[0]);
```

For more on e4x, this is a good primer:
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=4

Comment: I have a error:
TypeError: Error #1085: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qktfpe2HNX3eqkbE8Y3sXodWmVayKfjpxOW98rEUHV8/edit

Comment: I see no link tag in your question, loading in complex html pages (like stackoverflow home page) will always be tricky because they don't always comply to XML standards.  That error is because the link tags on stackoverflow don't have the trailing / on their tag, which makes the markup malformed causing that error.

Comment: If you're not in control of the html coming in, then you'd have to create some clean up function to make sure the markup is valid.  You could also just search the string for the data you want and forget about converting it to xml.