# Remove hyperlink, anchor tags from text in actionscript 3

Tags: regex, actionscript, hyperlink, anchor, strip

How I can remove all anchor tags from text. If I have string like:

```
< a href="a.aspx">aaaaa</a>
<b href="#">bbbbb</b>
tttttttt</a>
<a href = "#">ccccc< /a >
<a href="something.html">ddddd</a>
```

how I can remove al links so the final output is:

```
aaaaa
<b href="#">bbbbb</b>
tttttttt</a>
ccccc
ddddd
```

I need to do it in actionscript 3.

Thanks

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Example that "meets" the needs of your requirement: [`<\s*a\b.*?>(.*?)<\s*/a\s*>`](http://regex101.com/r/tX4fE6). AS3 documentation: [`String.replace(RegExp, String);`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace()). Finally: [a better way to parse a DOM in AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12184237/703229). Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here is an expanded answer based off of my comment, by request.*

---

First of all, ["regular" expressions should not be used to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) because HTML is not a "regular" language.  This can be seen in your example where multiple oddities can be used in anchor tags and they will all still be parsed as links by a browser.

But [`<\s*a\b.*?>(.*?)<\s*/a\s*>`](http://regex101.com/r/tX4fE6) is an expression that technically meets your requirements, so if your use case is "controlled" then go for it.  Here is an expanded explanation:

```
<\s*   (?# match < followed by 0+ whitespace)
a\b    (?# match a followed by a word boundary)
.*?>   (?# lazily match 0+ characters followed by >)
(.*?)  (?# lazily capture 0+ characters into group #1)
<\s*   (?# match < followed by 0+ whitespace)
/a     (?# match /a literally)
\s*>   (?# match 0+ whitespace characters followed by >)
```

---

**Notes:**

- `(...)` creates a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that can be [referenced](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) by `\1` or `$1` in your replacement string.
- I said this works for "controlled" use cases, but what does that mean?  This will fail on a link like [`<a href="foo>bar">fail</a>`](http://regex101.com/r/tA9xP6) which is technically an invalid URL, but most programs reading HTML will handle this fine.
- AS3 documentation: [`String.replace(RegExp, String);`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace())
- So I said its a bad idea to use regex for HTML, but [what do you use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183788/flex-string-to-html-for-parse-with-dom/12184237#12184237)